# Partial file not found in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am getting following error.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The partial view '../Shared/Partial/_ReferencePartial.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

I am having login controller in `Area/Admin`. In `Login.cshtml` view file, I am referencing `Partial View` file that contains references to script files. This file is in the folder, `Solution/Project/Views/Shared/Partial`.

Below is my `Login.cshtml` view file code.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@Messages.Login</title>

    @Html.Partial("../Shared/Partial/_ReferencePartial.cshtml")
</head>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the partial view directly inside the main view you could use the `Html.Action` helper:

```
@Html.Action("Load", "Home")
```

or if you don't want to go through the Load action use the HtmlPartial hepler:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoadView")
```

If you want to use `Ajax.ActionLink`, replace your `Html.ActionLink` with:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "load partial view", 
    "Load", 
    "Home", 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }
)
```

and of course you need to include a holder in your page where the partial will be displayed:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Also don't forget to include:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in your main view in order to enable `Ajax.*` helpers. And make sure that unobtrusive javascript is enabled in your web.config (it should be by default):

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: the partial view file only contains references to script files. that means the file only contains `script` and `link` tags and `@Scripts.Render`.

Comment: @DhavalR, i think your code will work if you go with first or second way. you just wanted to load the partial view only..